# WordPress login form centered

Tags: css, wordpress

Anybody here can help me how to center my login/sign up form?

This is my website https://www.cryptobank.expert/ you will be asked to login, that's the form I want to center. My problem is I dont know what name should I edit in the CSS.

Comment: Add the following snippet in Custom CSS Panel

.xoo-el-form-container.xoo-el-form-inline {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    display: block;
}

Comment: it worked like a charm. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work

```
.ns-form-horizontal .ns-control-label {
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 7px;
}
```

Comment: hi i tried it but it was the label that moved to the left. the text field was not moved

Comment: The container which holds the text field is pulling the Columns CSS to following: "ns-col-md-9 ns-col-sm-9 ns-col-xs-12" which is set to 75%. You need to tweak the template file to make it 100%, which means you should assign the template with a larger column class. If you provide access i can a take a look at it.

Comment: i already did changing the css. but it doesnt work i really dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet in Custom CSS Panel

```
.xoo-el-form-container.xoo-el-form-inline {
margin: 0 auto !important;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: hi it worked thank you. can I ask also about my support form. the same thing i want to do. I tried your css above but it doesnt work at this time

website page: https://www.cryptobank.expert/withdraw-funds/

I want that the SUBJECT TEXT FIELD will be aligned with the text above. It doesn't matter if the SUBJECT LABEL will be indented to the left. I tried the same css you gave but it doesnt apply for this div class